# `summarize()` the Power Set of Grouping Variables in R

Tags: performance, r, power-set, dplyr

## Background

On a whim, I wrote a function called `summarize_pow()`.  It performs [`dplyr::summarize()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) on `.data` for every subset (ie. the [**power set**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)) of its [`group_vars()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_data.html), to yield a `list` of `tibble`s.  It optionally consolidates these into a single `tibble` via [`bind_rows()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind_rows.html), with (optional) identifying columns.

I initially wrote my own `.power_set()` helper, but I found that [`rje::powerSet()`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rje/html/powerSet.html) is up to 20 times more efficient.  While [`HapEstXXR::powerset()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/HapEstXXR/man/powerset.html) seems ([here](https://rdrr.io/cran/HapEstXXR/src/R/powerset.R)) to be implemented in C ([here](https://github.com/cran/HapEstXXR/blob/master/src/powerset.c)?) and likely outperforms both, it seems to be no longer maintained.

## Questions

1. How can I optimize performance when generating power sets?
2. Is `.tmp_name()` stable for all possible [`names()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/names.html) in a [`tibble`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tibble.html)?  Does this hold for all [name repairs](https://vctrs.r-lib.org/reference/vec_as_names.html)?
3. How can I best mimic the [`.by`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html#arguments) argument to `summarize()`? As a <[`tidyselect`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html)> argument, it must be evaluated in the context of `.data`; but we only need the *names* of those variables, so something like [`rlang::eval_tidy()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/eval_tidy.html) might waste resources on returning their *data*.

See the **Code** section for my source code, the **Manual** section for its documentation, and the **Example** section for a demonstration.

## Example

Here we analyze [`got_chars`](https://jennybc.github.io/repurrrsive/reference/got_chars.html) for the cohorts of characters in greatest danger from GRRM's bloody pen.

Note that I import my module via [`box::use()`](https://klmr.me/box/reference/use.html), so the [**`box`**](https://klmr.me/box) package should be installed. My code is saved as `pow.R` in the current directory: hence `box::use(./pow)`.

```r
# Load the libraries...
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# ...and the datasets.
library(repurrrsive)



# Load "pow" itself...
box::use(./pow); attach(pow)

# # ...and refresh as needed.
# detach(pow); box::reload(pow); attach(pow)

# Learn about 'summarize_pow()'.
box::help(pow$summarize_pow)



# Tabulate the GoT dataset.
got_df <- got_chars %>% tibble() %>% unnest_wider(1)
got_df



# Analyze death rates in GoT.
x_x <- got_df %>%
  
  # Define the cohorts.
  group_by(culture, gender) %>%
  
  # Summarize for every possible cohort...
  summarize_pow(
    .max_n = Inf,                     # Process without limits.
    .id = T, .n = T, .vars = T,       # Include all info columns.
    
    data = list(pick(everything())),  # Capture the group of data.
    n_total = n(),                    # Record the sample size.
    n_alive = sum(alive)              # Count the living.
  ) %>%
  
  # ...and the death rate.
  mutate(
    n_dead = n_total - n_alive,    # Count the deceased.
    death_rate = n_dead / n_total  # Calculate the rate.
  ) %>%
  
  # Focus on samples of viable size.
  filter(n_total > 1) %>%
  
  # Sort by highest death rate.
  arrange(desc(death_rate))
```

> ```
> Warning message:
> `.max_n` should generally be an integer in [0, 30], but rarely `Inf`.
> ℹ This is for the sake of efficiency.
> ```

```r
# View the entire result.
x_x %>% print(n = Inf)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 14 × 10
>      .id    .n .vars     culture    gender data               n_total n_alive n_dead death_rate
>    <int> <int> <list>    <chr>      <chr>  <list>               <int>   <int>  <int>      <dbl>
>  1     2     1 <chr [1]> "Rivermen" NA     <tibble [2 × 17]>        2       0      2      1    
>  2     4     2 <chr [2]> ""         Male   <tibble [5 × 16]>        5       1      4      0.8  
>  3     2     1 <chr [1]> ""         NA     <tibble [6 × 17]>        6       2      4      0.667
>  4     2     1 <chr [1]> "Dornish"  NA     <tibble [2 × 17]>        2       1      1      0.5  
>  5     3     1 <chr [1]>  NA        Male   <tibble [21 × 17]>      21      12      9      0.429
>  6     1     0 <chr [0]>  NA        NA     <tibble [30 × 18]>      30      20     10      0.333
>  7     4     2 <chr [2]> "Northmen" Male   <tibble [3 × 16]>        3       2      1      0.333
>  8     2     1 <chr [1]> "Northmen" NA     <tibble [5 × 17]>        5       4      1      0.2  
>  9     3     1 <chr [1]>  NA        Female <tibble [9 × 17]>        9       8      1      0.111
> 10     2     1 <chr [1]> "Ironborn" NA     <tibble [4 × 17]>        4       4      0      0    
> 11     2     1 <chr [1]> "Westeros" NA     <tibble [2 × 17]>        2       2      0      0    
> 12     4     2 <chr [2]> "Ironborn" Male   <tibble [3 × 16]>        3       3      0      0    
> 13     4     2 <chr [2]> "Westeros" Male   <tibble [2 × 16]>        2       2      0      0    
> 14     4     2 <chr [2]> "Northmen" Female <tibble [2 × 16]>        2       2      0      0
> ```

## Code

### Current **`pow`** Module

This is the latest version of my code.  Save as `pow.R` for the **Example**.

```r
###############
###############
####  API  ####
###############
###############

#####
#' @title Summarise Combinations of Groups
#' @description Summarise a dataset for every \emph{subset} of its grouping
#'   variables: the \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set}{"power
#'   set"}.
#' @export
#####
#' @param .data A data frame, data frame extension (e.g. a
#'   \href{https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tbl_df-class.html}{\code{tibble}}),
#'   or a lazy data frame (e.g. from
#'   \href{https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org}{\strong{\code{dbplyr}}} or
#'   \href{https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org}{\strong{\code{dtplyr}}}). See
#'   \href{https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html#arguments}{\code{dplyr::summarise()}}
#'   for details.
#' @param ...
#'   <\href{https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/args_data_masking.html}{\code{data-masking}}>
#'   Name-value pairs of summary functions. The name will be the name of the
#'   variable in the result. See \code{dplyr::summarise()} for details.
#  @param .by
#    <\href{https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html}{\code{tidy-select}}>
#    Optionally, a selection of columns to group by for just this operation,
#    functioning as an alternative to
#    \href{https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html}{\code{dplyr::group_by()}}.
#    See \code{dplyr::summarise()} for details.
#' @param .max_n \code{integer} in \code{[0, 32]}. The maximum number of
#'   variables to ever group by; use
#'   \href{https://rdrr.io/r/base/is.finite.html}{\code{Inf}} for limitless
#'   processing. Set \code{.max_n} to limit \strong{exponential} complexity of
#'   time and space: \strong{(2ⁿ)} as described under \strong{Details}.
#'   
#'   Defaults to \code{max_n(fast = TRUE)} for performance, so see
#'   \code{max_n()} for details.
#' @param .condense \code{logical} boolean. Should the results for every subset
#'   be consolidated (\code{TRUE}) into a single \code{tibble}? Defaults to
#'   \code{TRUE} for immediate consolidation.
#' @param .id \code{character} string or
#'   \href{https://rdrr.io/r/base/name.html}{\code{symbol}}. The name of an
#'   optional (\code{integer}) column, which \emph{indexes} the particular
#'   subset of grouping variables being used; use \code{TRUE} as a shortcut for
#'   \code{".id"}. Defaults to \code{NULL} to omit this column altogether.
#' @param .n \code{character} string or \code{symbol}. The name of an optional
#'   (\code{integer}) column, which \emph{counts} the particular grouping
#'   variables being used; use \code{TRUE} as a shortcut for \code{".n"}.
#'   Defaults to \code{NULL} to omit this column altogether.
#' @param .vars \code{character} string or \code{symbol}. The name of an
#'   optional
#'   \href{https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#list-columns}{list-column},
#'   which \emph{names} (with a \code{character} vector) the particular grouping
#'   variables being used; use \code{TRUE} as a shortcut for \code{".vars"}.
#'   Defaults to \code{NULL} to omit this column altogether.
#' 
#' @details \code{summarise_pow()} starts with the set \strong{} of grouping
#'   variables for \code{.data}:
#    either the explicit \code{.by} or
#'   the implicit
#'   \href{https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_data.html}{\code{dplyr::group_vars()}}.
#'   Using
#'   \href{https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rje/html/powerSet.html}{\code{rje::powerSet()}},
#'   it then takes the \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set}{power set}
#'   \strong{()}: the set of all \emph{subsets} of \strong{}.
#'   
#' \preformatted{
#' grp_vars <- c("a", "b", "c")
#' 
#' pwr_set <- rje::powerSet(grp_vars)
#' pwr_set
#' #> [[1]]
#' #> character(0)
#' #> 
#' #> [[2]]
#' #> [1] "a"
#' #> 
#' #> [[3]]
#' #> [1] "b"
#' #> 
#' #> [[4]]
#' #> [1] "a" "b"
#' #> 
#' #> [[5]]
#' #> [1] "c"
#' #> 
#' #> [[6]]
#' #> [1] "a" "c"
#' #> 
#' #> [[7]]
#' #> [1] "b" "c"
#' #> 
#' #> [[8]]
#' #> [1] "a" "b" "c"
#' }
#'   
#'   With \strong{|| = } grouping variables, there will be \strong{|()|
#'   = 2ⁿ} such subsets: the
#'   \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Properties}{cardinality} of
#'   \strong{()}.
#'   
#' \preformatted{
#' n <- length(grp_vars)
#' n
#' #> 3
#' 
#' length(pwr_set)
#' #> 8
#' 
#' length(pwr_set) == 2^n
#' #> TRUE
#' }
#'   
#'   This translates into \strong{(2ⁿ)} complexity for both space and
#'   \href{https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/121328}{time}. As such, you might wish
#'   to limit \code{summarise_pow()} to subsets \emph{no larger} than
#'   \code{.max_n} variables.
#'   
#' \preformatted{
#' .max_n <- 1
#' 
#' rje::powerSet(grp_vars, m = .max_n)
#' #> [[1]]
#' #> character(0)
#' #> 
#' #> [[2]]
#' #> [1] "a"
#' #> 
#' #> [[3]]
#' #> [1] "b"
#' #> 
#' #> [[4]]
#' #> [1] "c"
#' }
#    
#    Grouping by each of these subsets in turn, \code{summarise_pow()} then
#    performs
#    \href{https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html}{\code{dplyr::summarise()}}
#    on \code{.data}. The result (\code{.condense = FALSE}) is a \code{list} of
#    \href{https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tbl_df-class.html}{\code{tibble}}s:
#    one for each subset.
#'   
#'   When consolidating (\code{.condense = TRUE}) everything into a single
#'   \code{tibble}, you may optionally \emph{prepend} any of the "information
#'   columns": \code{.id}, \code{.n}, and \code{.vars}. They describe the
#'   subsets like so:
#'   
#'   \tabular{rcrcl}{
#      #################           ################           #######################    
#'     \bold{\code{.id}} \tab \tab \bold{\code{.n}} \tab \tab \bold{\code{.vars}}     \cr
#      #################           ################           #######################    
#'              \code{1} \tab \tab         \code{0} \tab \tab \code{character(0)}     \cr
#'              \code{2} \tab \tab         \code{1} \tab \tab \code{c("a")}           \cr
#'              \code{3} \tab \tab         \code{1} \tab \tab \code{c("b")}           \cr
#'              \code{4} \tab \tab         \code{2} \tab \tab \code{c("a", "b")}      \cr
#'              \code{5} \tab \tab         \code{1} \tab \tab \code{c("c")}           \cr
#'              \code{6} \tab \tab         \code{2} \tab \tab \code{c("a", "c")}      \cr
#'              \code{7} \tab \tab         \code{2} \tab \tab \code{c("b", "c")}      \cr
#'              \code{8} \tab \tab         \code{3} \tab \tab \code{c("a", "b", "c")} \cr
#      #################           ################           #######################    
#'   }
#' 
#' @return For \code{.condense = FALSE}, a \code{list} with one
#'   \href{https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tbl_df-class.html}{\code{tibble}}
#'   for every \emph{subset} of the grouping variables for \code{.data}. Each
#'   \code{tibble} is the result of performing
#'   \href{https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html}{\code{dplyr::summarise()}}
#'   on \code{.data}, as grouped by that subset.
#'   
#'   For \code{.condense = TRUE}, a single \code{tibble} consolidated from that
#'   \code{list} via
#'   \href{https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind_rows.html}{\code{dplyr::bind_rows()}}.
#'   When names are supplied for the "information columns" (\code{.id},
#'   \code{.n}, and \code{.vars}), those columns are prepended to the output.
#####
summarise_pow <- function(.data, ...,
  # .by = NULL,
  .max_n = max_n(TRUE),
  .condense = TRUE,
  .id = NULL, .n = NULL, .vars = NULL
) {
  # Sanitize inputs.
  .check_max_n(.max_n)
  
  .condense <- isTRUE(.condense)
  .id <- .clean_col(.id, default = ".id")
  .n <- .clean_col(.n, default = ".n")
  .vars <- .clean_col(.vars, default = ".vars")
  
  
  # Extract the column names...
  all_vars <- colnames(.data)
  
  # ...the grouping variables...
  # if (is.null(.by)) {
  grp_vars <- dplyr::group_vars(.data)
  # } else {
  #   ...
  # }
  
  # # ...and their locations.
  # grp_locs <- match(grp_vars, all_vars)
  
  # ...and count them.
  n_vars <- length(grp_vars)
  
  
  # Warn the user if '.max_n' has excluded some combinations.
  .check_n_vars(n_vars, .data, .max_n)
  
  
  # Find every combination of grouping variables.
  grp_sets <- rje::powerSet(grp_vars, rev = FALSE)
  
  
  # Take the summary for every combination.
  summ <- lapply(grp_sets, function(set) {
    dplyr::summarize(dplyr::ungroup(.data), ... = ..., .by = set)
  })
  
  
  # Optionally condense the summaries.
  if (.condense) {
    # Name the desired info columns.
    info_cols <- c(.id, .n, .vars)
    
    # Generate a temporary '.id' variable as needed.
    if (is.null(.n) && is.null(.vars)) {
      is_tmp <- FALSE
    } else if (is.null(.id)) {
      .id <- .tmp_name(colnames(summ), new = ".id")
      is_tmp <- TRUE
    } else {
      is_tmp <- FALSE
    }
    
    # Stack the summaries...
    summ <- dplyr::bind_rows(... = unname(summ), .id = .id)
    
    # ...and cast any '.id' to an integer.
    if (!is.null(.id))
      summ[[.id]] <- as.integer(summ[[.id]])
    
    # Attach the number '.n' of variables in each combination. 
    if (!is.null(.n)) {
      n_col <- vapply(grp_sets, length, FUN.VALUE = integer(1))
      # n_col <- .power_n(n_vars)
      summ[[.n]] <- n_col[summ[[.id]]]
    }
    
    # Attach the vector '.vars' of variable names in each combination.
    if (!is.null(.vars)){
      summ[[.vars]] <- grp_sets[summ[[.id]]]
    }
    
    # Delete any temporary '.id'.
    if (is_tmp)
      summ[.id] <- NULL
    
    # Reorganize the columns:
    # '.id' | '.n' | '.vars' | 'grp_1' | ... | 'grp_n' | 'agg_1' | ... | 'agg_n'
    first_cols <- c(info_cols, grp_vars, all_vars)
    
    summ <- dplyr::relocate(summ, dplyr::any_of(first_cols), .before = 1)
  }
  
  
  # Return the result.
  summ
}



#####
#' @rdname summarise_pow
#' @description \code{summarise_pow()} and \code{summarize_pow()} are
#'   synonyms.
#' @export
#####
summarize_pow <- summarise_pow



#####
#' @title Limit Complexity
#' @description Retrieve size limits on (sub)sets of grouping variables for
#'   \code{summarise_pow()}.
#' @export
#####
#' @param fast \code{logical} boolean. Retrieve the relative limit (\code{TRUE})
#'   for fast performance, or the absolute limit (\code{FALSE}) on functional
#'   memory.
#'   
#' @return A single \code{integer} with the maximum number of variables
#'   permitted in a (sub)set.
#####
max_n <- function(fast = FALSE) {
  max_n <- log2(as.integer(.MAX_VEC_LEN))
  max_n <- max(0, floor(max_n))
  
  if (isTRUE(fast)) {
    max_n_fast <- max(0, as.integer(.MAX_N_FAST))
    max_n <- min(max_n_fast, max_n)
  }
  
  as.integer(max_n)
}





###################
###################
####  Support  ####
###################
###################

# The longest vector permitted in R.
.MAX_VEC_LEN <- 2 ^ 31 - 1

# The experimental "event horizon" for |x| at which 'rje::powerSet(x)' bogs down for (x).
.MAX_N_FAST <- 22


# Clean (and interpret) the names for the "information columns".
.clean_col <- function(x, default = NULL) {
  if (is.null(x))
    NULL
  else if (isTRUE(x))
    rlang::as_string(default)
  else if (isFALSE(x))
    NULL
  else
    rlang::as_string(x)
}


# Check that '.max_n' does not restrict 'n_vars'.
.check_n_vars <- function(n, data, max) {
  data_sym <- rlang::caller_arg(data)
  max_sym <- rlang::caller_arg(max)
  
  if (max < n) {
    warn_fmt <- "%s = %.0f is less than the number (%d) of grouping variables in %s."
    warn_msg <- sprintf(warn_fmt,
      rlang:::format_arg(max_sym),
      max,
      n,
      rlang:::format_arg(data_sym)
    )
    
    warn_i <- "This excludes larger combinations of grouping variables."
    warn_msg <- c(warn_msg, i = warn_i)
    warn_call <- rlang::caller_env(n = 2)
    
    rlang::warn(warn_msg, call = warn_call)
  }
}


# Check that '.max_n' is a valid input to 'summarise_pow()'.
.check_max_n <- function(x) {
  x_sym <- rlang::ensym(x)
  max_n <- max_n(FALSE)
  
  # Permit a whole integer in [0, 30]...
  if (
    rlang::is_scalar_integerish(x, finite = TRUE) &&
    x >= 0 && x <= max_n
  ) {
    return(invisible(x))
    
    # ...warn about an integer above 30...
  } else if (
    rlang::is_scalar_integerish(x, finite = TRUE) &&
    x > max_n
  ) {
    sig_class <- "warning"
    sig_fmt <- "%s should generally be %s, but rarely %s."
    sig_val <- sprintf("an integer in [0, %d]", max_n)
    sig_i <- "This is for the sake of efficiency."
    sig_call <- NULL
    
    # ...warn about +Inf...
  } else if (
    rlang::is_scalar_integerish(x, finite = FALSE) &&
    x == Inf
  ) {
    sig_class <- "warning"
    sig_fmt <- "%s should generally be %s, but rarely %s."
    sig_val <- sprintf("an integer in [0, %d]", max_n)
    sig_i <- "This is for the sake of efficiency."
    sig_call <- NULL
    
    # ...and error for anything else.
  } else {
    sig_class <- "error"
    sig_fmt <- "%s must be %s, but never %s."
    sig_val <- c(
      "a positive integer",
      rlang:::obj_type_friendly(Inf)
    )
    sig_i <- NULL
    sig_call <- rlang::caller_env(n = 2)
  }
  
  # Assemble the condition...
  sig_arg <- rlang::caller_arg(x)
  sig_val <- rlang:::oxford_comma(sig_val, final = "or")
  
  sig_msg <- sprintf(sig_fmt,
    rlang:::format_arg(sig_arg),
    sig_val,
    rlang:::obj_type_friendly(x, value = TRUE)
  )
  sig_msg <- c(sig_msg, i = sig_i)
  
  # ...and signal it accordingly.
  rlang::signal(sig_msg, class = sig_class, call = sig_call, arg = sig_arg)
  
  
  # Return the value where permitted.
  return(invisible(x))
}


# Generate a syntactically valid set of names, in the context of existing names.
.tmp_name <- function(old, new, unique = TRUE, allow_ = TRUE) {
  # old <- as.character(old)
  # 
  # if (is.numeric(new)) {
  #   # start <- max(old, na.rm = TRUE)
  #   # if (!is.na(start))
  #   start <- "x"
  #   
  #   new <- rep(start, times = new)
  # } else {
  #   new <- as.character(new)
  # }
  
  n_new <- length(new)
  
  if (n_new == 0)
    return(character(0))
  
  old <- unique(old)
  new <- make.names(c(old, new), unique = unique, allow_ = allow_)
  utils::tail(new, n = n_new)
}
```

### Current `.tmp_name()` Function

Excerpted from **`pow`**, this function is a helper for `summarize_pow()`.  It ensures (in theory) that the [`.id`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind_rows.html#arguments) argument to `bind_rows()` never clashes with existing column names.

```r
# Generate a syntactically valid set of names, in the context of existing names.
.tmp_name <- function(old, new, unique = TRUE, allow_ = TRUE) {
  n_new <- length(new)
  
  if (n_new == 0)
    return(character(0))
  
  old <- unique(old)
  new <- make.names(c(old, new), unique = unique, allow_ = allow_)
  utils::tail(new, n = n_new)
}
```

### Former `power_*()` Functions

These functions were originally **`pow`** helpers for `summarize_pow()`.  Due to performance, `.power_set()` is deprecated in favor of `rje::powerSet()`.  Since `rje::powerSet()` generates its subsets in a different order, then lengths (for the **`.n`** column) must be calculated via [`length()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/length.html) rather than `.power_n()`.

```r
.power_set <- function(x, unique = TRUE) {
  if(unique)
    x <- unique(x)
  n <- length(x)
  
  if (n == 0)
    return(list(x))
  
  # Calculate the total number of subsets: |(x)| = 2ⁿ where n = |x|.
  m <- 2 ^ n
  
  # Generate the sequence: 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 2ⁿ - 1
  seq <- 1:m - 1
  
  # Convert the sequence into binary and then boolean vectors.
  # ======  ========  ========
  #      0  000...00  FFF...FF
  #      1  000...01  FFF...FT
  #      2  000...10  FFF...TF
  #      3  000...11  FFF...TT
  #      ⋮       ⋮         ⋮
  # 2ⁿ - 1  111...11  TTT...TT
  idx <- vapply(seq, FUN = intToBits, FUN.VALUE = raw(32))
  idx <- utils::head(idx, n = n)
  idx <- idx == 1
  
  # Extract every subset from x, using the corresponding boolean vector.
  apply(idx, MARGIN = 2, subset, x = x, simplify = FALSE)
}


# Mathematically calculate the sizes {|p|: p in (S)} of every subset of S, where |S| = 'n_vars'.
.power_n <- function(n_vars) {
  set_sizes <- 0:n_vars
  rep(set_sizes, times = choose(n_vars, set_sizes))
}
```

## Manual

To clarify my intent, I have reproduced the help pages (below), accessible via [`box::help()`](https://klmr.me/box/reference/help.html).

### Page for `summarize_pow()`

> ## Summarise Combinations of Groups
>
> ### Description
>
> Summarise a dataset for every *subset* of its grouping
> variables: the ["power
> set"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).
>
> `summarise_pow()` and `summarize_pow()` are
> synonyms.
>
> ### Usage
>
> ```r
> summarise_pow(
>   .data,
>   ...,
>   .max_n = max_n(TRUE),
>   .condense = TRUE,
>   .id = NULL,
>   .n = NULL,
>   .vars = NULL
> )
> summarize_pow(
>   .data,
>   ...,
>   .max_n = max_n(TRUE),
>   .condense = TRUE,
>   .id = NULL,
>   .n = NULL,
>   .vars = NULL
> )
> ```
>
> ### Arguments
>
> | Argument | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `.data` | A data frame, data frame extension (e.g. a [`tibble`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tbl_df-class.html)), or a lazy data frame (e.g. from [**`dbplyr`**](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org) or [**`dtplyr`**](https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org)). See [`dplyr::summarise()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html#arguments) for details. |
> | `...` | <[`data-masking`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/args_data_masking.html)> Name-value pairs of summary functions. The name will be the name of the variable in the result. See `dplyr::summarise()` for details. |
> | `.max_n` | `integer` in `[0, 32]`. The maximum number of variables to ever group by; use [`Inf`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/is.finite.html) for limitless processing. Set `.max_n` to limit **exponential** complexity of time and space: **(2ⁿ)** as described under **Details**. Defaults to `max_n(fast = TRUE)` for performance, so see `max_n()` for details. |
> | `.condense` | `logical` boolean. Should the results for every subset be consolidated (`TRUE`) into a single `tibble`? Defaults to `TRUE` for immediate consolidation. |
> | `.id` | `character` string or [`symbol`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/name.html). The name of an optional (`integer`) column, which *indexes* the particular subset of grouping variables being used; use `TRUE` as a shortcut for `".id"`. Defaults to `NULL` to omit this column altogether. |
> | `.n` | `character` string or `symbol`. The name of an optional (`integer`) column, which *counts* the particular grouping variables being used; use `TRUE` as a shortcut for `".n"`. Defaults to `NULL` to omit this column altogether. |
> | `.vars` | `character` string or `symbol`. The name of an optional [list-column](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#list-columns), which *names* (with a `character` vector) the particular grouping variables being used; use `TRUE` as a shortcut for `".vars"`. Defaults to `NULL` to omit this column altogether. |
>
> ### Details
>
> `summarise_pow()` starts with the set  of grouping
> variables for `.data`:
> the implicit
> [`dplyr::group_vars()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_data.html).
> Using
> [`rje::powerSet()`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rje/html/powerSet.html),
> it then takes the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)
> **()**: the set of all *subsets* of .
>
> ```
>  grp_vars <- c("a", "b", "c")
>  
>  pwr_set <- rje::powerSet(grp_vars)
>  pwr_set
>  #> [[1]]
>  #> character(0)
>  #> 
>  #> [[2]]
>  #> [1] "a"
>  #> 
>  #> [[3]]
>  #> [1] "b"
>  #> 
>  #> [[4]]
>  #> [1] "a" "b"
>  #> 
>  #> [[5]]
>  #> [1] "c"
>  #> 
>  #> [[6]]
>  #> [1] "a" "c"
>  #> 
>  #> [[7]]
>  #> [1] "b" "c"
>  #> 
>  #> [[8]]
>  #> [1] "a" "b" "c"
> ```
>
> With **|| =**  grouping variables, there will be **|()|
> = 2ⁿ** such subsets: the
> [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Properties) of
> **()**.
>
> ```
>  n <- length(grp_vars)
>  n
>  #> 3
>  
>  length(pwr_set)
>  #> 8
>  
>  length(pwr_set) == 2^n
>  #> TRUE
> ```
>
> This translates into **(2ⁿ)** complexity for both space and
> [time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/121328). As such, you might wish
> to limit `summarise_pow()` to subsets *no larger* than
> `.max_n` variables.
>
> ```
>  .max_n <- 1
>  
>  rje::powerSet(grp_vars, m = .max_n)
>  #> [[1]]
>  #> character(0)
>  #> 
>  #> [[2]]
>  #> [1] "a"
>  #> 
>  #> [[3]]
>  #> [1] "b"
>  #> 
>  #> [[4]]
>  #> [1] "c"
> ```
>
> When consolidating (`.condense = TRUE`) everything into a single
> `tibble`, you may optionally *prepend* any of the "information
> columns": `.id`, `.n`, and `.vars`. They describe the
> subsets like so:
>
> | **`.id`** | **`.n`** | **`.vars`** |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `1` | `0` | `character(0)` |
> | `2` | `1` | `c("a")` |
> | `3` | `1` | `c("b")` |
> | `4` | `2` | `c("a", "b")` |
> | `5` | `1` | `c("c")` |
> | `6` | `2` | `c("a", "c")` |
> | `7` | `2` | `c("b", "c")` |
> | `8` | `3` | `c("a", "b", "c")` |
>
> ### Value
>
> For `.condense = FALSE`, a `list` with one
> [`tibble`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tbl_df-class.html)
> for every *subset* of the grouping variables for `.data`. Each
> `tibble` is the result of performing
> [`dplyr::summarise()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html)
> on `.data`, as grouped by that subset.
>
> For `.condense = TRUE`, a single `tibble` consolidated from that
> `list` via
> [`dplyr::bind_rows()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind_rows.html).
> When names are supplied for the "information columns" (`.id`,
> `.n`, and `.vars`), those columns are prepended to the output.

### Page for `max_n()`

> ## Limit Complexity
>
> ### Description
>
> Retrieve size limits on (sub)sets of grouping variables for
> `summarise_pow()`.
>
> ### Usage
>
> ```r
> max_n(fast = FALSE)
> ```
>
> ### Arguments
>
> | Argument | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `fast` | `logical` boolean. Retrieve the relative limit (`TRUE`) for fast performance, or the absolute limit (`FALSE`) on functional memory. |
>
> ### Value
>
> A single `integer` with the maximum number of variables
> permitted in a (sub)set.